# Is it possible to ensure separate Java environments for applets when spawning a new browser window?

Tags: applet, signed-applet

I am trying to solve a problem where 2 different web pages have signed applets which *seem* to be causing problems for each other. The first page contains an applet which spawns a new browser window and sets the URL to the second page. Something like this...

```
cmd /c start iexplore.exe page2.html
```

Some tracing infomation suggests that the two applets are sharing the same heap and this might be causing the problems.

Is there any way to ensure a complete separation?

Answer (score 1):

See the [`Separate_VM`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/plugin2-142482.html#SEPARATE_JVM) param.

> A boolean parameter specifying that a particular applet should
>   run in its **own JVM instance.** This supports certain powerful desktop
>   applets which can not tolerate any interference from other applets
>   running in the same JVM and potentially consuming heap space or other
>   resources.